# read text file and store values in matrix. How to deal with new line char

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm reading a text file and storing the values into an array in C#. Here's the code:

```
private void btn_readfile_text_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.tmp"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var numbers = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                {
                   //do something with numbers[i]
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(except.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what's inside the text file:

```
V  Q  -55.731934  45.378296  -46.411377  0.093072  0.906675  0.030127  -0.409966 16372266l
;5437 ÿ
V  Q  -56.731934  46.378296  -46.411377  0.093072  0.906675  0.030127  -0.409966 16372266l
;5437 ÿ
V  Q  -57.731934  47.378296  -46.411377  0.093072  0.906675  0.030127  -0.409966 16372266l
;5437 ÿ
V  Q  -58.731934  48.378296  -46.411377  0.093072  0.906675  0.030127  -0.409966 16372266l
;5437 ÿ
V  Q  -59.731934  49.378296  -46.411377  0.093072  0.906675  0.030127  -0.409966 16372266l
;5437 ÿ
```

Now, when I look at the array matrix, every new "V" character has a little ? preceding it, what might that be? I think is the new line character but not sure, how can I get rid of that?

Comment: That's [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS' (U+00FF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff/index.htm), character 255.  It's not a newline.  Perhaps whatever wrote that file placed it there on purpose?  Or on accident?

Comment: how can I check if it is there because in the txt file itself I don't see it..

Comment: Do you have a text editor that can view the file as a hex dump, such as Notepad++?  If so, try one of those.  It will let you view the actual byte values.  Character 255 will show up as `FF`.